# How to control the elevation of the material toolbar according to my own preference?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

This is my layout file and as you can see, instead of using the AppBars that come included with themes, I am using a custom toolbar.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dice_roller_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView.../>

    <Button.../>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIfA7.jpg

(Notice that there is no `elevation` attribute used here).

I am extending from the `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` theme to be able to use my own custom `ToolBar`. Now the problem is that, I can't find a way to change the elevation of the toolbar. To change the elevation, I tried to use `android:elevation` attribute inside the <AppBarLayout> tag like so:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        ...
        android:elevation="4dp"
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar.../>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

and it made no difference as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQuGA.jpg)
(I have tried all the values from 0dp to 4dp, it doesn't make a difference)

Then I added the same `android:elevation` attribute inside the child tag of <AppBarLayout>, namely the <MaterialToolbar> tag like so:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout...>

         <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
              android:id="@+id/activity_toolbar"
              ...
              android:elevation="4dp"
              ... />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

and this resulted in a horrible mess like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDs1i.jpg)
which is definitely not what I want.

Then I tried `app:elevation` attribute which didn't make any changes when used inside the <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar/> tag no matter the value I used but when I tried the same `app:elevation` attribute inside <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>, it removed the little bit of elevation that can be seen in the [original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIfA7.jpg) (which shows the state of the app when no `elevation` attributes were used) and made it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2WQX.jpg) (notice that there is no elevation in the top bar anymore).

I don't just wanna add more elevation or reduce the elevation, I want to be able to control it. I know that there is already enough elevation that abides by the material guidelines but I want to make it like the Google News app where there is no elevation or I might wanna make it like the settings page in stock android where there is just enough elevation to make it look both beautiful and distinguishable from the rest of the layout.

If more information is needed, you can check out the github repo for this app that I have made: https://github.com/sbeve72/diceroller/tree/unguided-development

PS: I am a beginner and you might have noticed this just the first app you make when taking the Udacity course by google.

Comment: Use `app:elevation` in the `AppBarLayout`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Bro you didn't even read the question well

> ""but when I tried the same app:elevation attribute inside <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>, it removed the little bit of elevation that can be seen in the original screenshot (which shows the state of the app when no elevation attributes were used) and made it look like this (notice that there is no elevation in the top bar anymore).""

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `AppBarLayout` and set `android:background` on your `MaterialToolbar`, elevation can be controlled by `android:elevation` then:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="0dp" />
```

Check with the newest Material Design Library stable version 1.4

Comment: indeed some tutorials have appbarlayout, but the materialtoolbar doc suggests to use it as standalone